# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, foreign-keys

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand(
"INSERT INTO tblBook(BookCode, BookTitle, Author, PublishingYear, 
                     Price, EnterDate, CatID, RackID, Amount) 
VALUES('" & txtBookCode.Text & "','" & 
            txtTitle.Text & "','" & 
            txtAuthor.Text & "','" & 
            txtPublishYear.Text & "','" & 
            txtPrice.Text & "', #" & 
            txtEnterDate.Text & "#, " & 
            txtCategory.ValueMember & "," & 
            txtRack.ValueMember & "," & 
            txtAmount.Text & ")"
, myConnection)
```

The error was:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREING KEY constraint "FK_tblBook_tblCategory". The 
>       conflict occurred in database "CIEDC", table "dbo.tblCategory", column 'CatID'.
>       The statement has been terminated.

Was that because of my database's relationships?

How can this be solved?

Comment: Yep you are right! it is because of the sql relationship, if possible post information about your tables and I can provide more specific help

Comment: Please start using parameters, such as @BookTitle instead of '" & txtTitle.Text & "'.  Any book title with a single quote will cause your insert to fail, plus avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: It's  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCategory]([CatID][int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [RackID][int] NOT NULL, [CategoryName][varchar](50) NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_tblCategory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CatID] ASC)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the value of `txtCategory.ValueMember` does not correspond to a valid category ID in your database.

Answer (score 0):

### I think there are two cases:

### 1.

In your table **dbo.tblBook,** it has a column named **CatID** act as foreign key reference to dbo.tblCategory table. It seems that you're trying to use  **CatID** property that haven't been created yet.if so, go back and create a **CatID** first.

### 2.

Maybe there are more than one foreign key that related to your table.
if you're using sql server so below sql statement will help you find all of them, check it out and drop the leftover, good luck!

```
    USE <database_name>;  
GO  
SELECT   
    f.name AS foreign_key_name  
   ,OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS table_name  
   ,COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS constraint_column_name  
   ,OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS referenced_object  
   ,COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS referenced_column_name  
   ,is_disabled  
   ,delete_referential_action_desc  
   ,update_referential_action_desc  
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f  
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc   
   ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id   
--WHERE f.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('HumanResources.Employee'); 
GO 
SELECT 
f.name AS foreign_key_name 
,OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS table_name 
,COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS constraint_column_name 
,OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS referenced_object 
,COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS referenced_column_name 
,is_disabled 
,delete_referential_action_desc 
,update_referential_action_desc 
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f 
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id 
--WHERE f.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('HumanResources.Employee');
```